# Bash read message every X seconds

Tags: bash

I want the `read` command to be able to use `read -t` without deleting the message after the timeout. basically, I need to read the data. After `t` seconds stop reading the data and save it in some variable.

For example: `read -t 5 msg` but after 5 seconds the message will still be at `msg` or any other variable

Comment: `{sleep 5; read msg;}`? `{timeout 5 cat >/dev/null ; read msg;}`? I do not understand, what do you want your program to do for these 5 seconds?

Comment: @KamilCuk I have clarified the question

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean "I want to read for five seconds, and get all the input the user types during that time even if they don't press Enter"?

Comment: @thatotherguy exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the terminal is line buffered, so bash never sees anything the user types until they press Enter.

To get around this, you will need to read character by character:

```sh
echo "Enter some data in 5 seconds:"
str=""
SECONDS=0
while ((SECONDS < 5))
do
  # Read one character with a very short timeout,
  # so that we can go back to checking the global timer
  IFS="" read -r -n 1 -d "" -t 0.1 c
  str+="$c"
done
echo
echo "Time's up. You wrote: $str"
```

Note that since line buffering is no longer used, you will need to include your own backspace handling.